# Format cell if non-blank and value is non-existing in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to create an Excel-formula where I format a cell via 'Conditional Formatting' to color a cell in a different color when the cell is non-blank AND the cell contains a non-existing value of another sheet as my current working one.

The code I came up with is not working, but it seems like a problem someone with proper Excel knowledge can fix. The formula is as follows:

```
IF(ISBLANK(B5) AND ISERROR(MATCH(B5;'My_Sheet'!$A$2:$A$223;0)))
```

I hope someone can help me fix this!

Comment: `=And(IsBlank(),IfError())` would be the syntax in conditional formatting, where you determine if it applies on true or false situation.

Comment: @Cyril If I replace my code with =IF(AND(ISBLANK(B5), ISERROR(MATCH(B5;'Eten per avond (Q1)'!$A$2:$A$223;0)))) it sadly still not works :(

Comment: Why did you add `if`?

Comment: @findwindow You're right, should've deleted that! However, it gives the formula error when I delete 'if' and the corresponding brackets :/

Comment: Conditional formatting formulas are not easy to reproduce / manipulate as the editing is nothing like editing a formula in a cell. My advice: create a new column with the complex formula desired that returns value(s) corresponding to the formatting(s) you desire. Then you can refer to this new column (and nothing else) to drive the formatting of the original column. That way, it is possible that if you change the formula, you won't have to change the conditional formula - or at least the  changes will be simpler

Answer (score 0):

Edited:  Intent from OP is `if NOT isblank() and iserror() then`; updating below accordingly.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1))=TRUE,ISERROR(MATCH($A1,Sheet2!$A1:$A5,0))=TRUE)
```

This allows you to check if something is not blank and that it's not found on the other sheet.

From sheet1, my input range with conditional format:

[image]

From sheet2, my range referenced:

[image]

Comment: I see what you are doing there, but I think this is not what I want. I have a colored sheet, but I want to make the cell another color when the cell is not blank AND the value is in another sheet. Now it also colors it when the cell is only empty, which is not what I want. I hope it makes sense haha :)

Comment: @MartijnSips thanks for clarifying; you need `and(not(isblank(),iserror(match()))` to support.  Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Cyril! This helped a lot. Sadly, the formula does not work for me. Which is weird, since I looks alright. `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B7));ISERROR(MATCH(B7;’Eten per avond (Q1)'!$A$2:$A$223;0)))`